# How to switch between multiple signals

Tags: arduino, rs485, rs232

I have a board that has a MAX232 and a MAX485. I want to switch between these peripherals' RX/TX signals which connected to Arduino. How would I achieve this?
I am definetly not knowledgeable about this topic and need some help.

[image]

Comment: Maybe using a multiplexer can help you please check here: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/multiplexing-serial-port-rx-tx/216905/5

Comment: @anilberg Yes, but I haven't a clue on how to use a multuplexer.

Comment: if you are only switching outputs, why bother? you could just drive both in parallel and leave both running. Unless you really do need to stop the output going to some destination under software control.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay for example you decided to use [SN74CBT3257C](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74cbt3257c.pdf) bidirectional multiplexer. According to datasheet you can use `1B1` and `1B2` pins as input of `MAX232_RX` and `MAX485_RX`. When `OE` chip enable pin is low, you can select between `MAX232_RX` and `MAX485_RX` by changing logic level of `S` (when `S = 1` then `1A = 1B2`, otherwise `1A = 1B1`).

With same way if you use `2B1` and `2B2` as an input of `MAX232_TX` and `MAX485_TX`.

[image]